# Creating JS function to operate on dynamically created variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code which works, but it very elementary in my opinion:

```
    var color1Default = $('.layer1').css('fill');
    $('#colorbox1').css('background-color', color1Default);

    var color2Default = $('.layer2').css('fill');
    $('#colorbox2').css('background-color', color2Default);

    var color3Default = $('.layer3').css('fill');
    $('#colorbox3').css('background-color', color3Default);
```

I have a variable that is created based on an echoed PHP variable. This variable is an integer value. This value can be different with any given page load. It comes from a db that says how many elements are needed. The html elements are created with a loop in PHP. The class of layer1, layer2, etc are referencing svg paths.

This is how I tried to simply this code:

```
    var numberColors = <?php echo $numColors; ?>;
    var colorDefault[];
    for (var i = 1; i <= numberColors; i++) {
        colorDefault[i] = 'colorDefault' + i;
    }

    for (var i=1; i <= numberColors; i++){
        colorDefault[i] = $('.layer' + i).css('fill');
        $('#colorbox' + i).css('background-color', colorDefault[i]);
    }
```

Am I approaching this anywhere near the way I should? Can you please help me not only to make this work, but to understand how to handle this problem in the future with similar problems?

Additionally, the following code is also repeated 12 times changing the numbers by hard coding them. How can I recreate this function to operate dynamically as well?

```
    $('#color1').on('input', function(){
            var newValue = $('#color1').val();

            if (newValue == ''){
                $('.layer1').css('fill', color1Default);
                $('#colorbox1').css('background-color', color1Default);
            } else {
                $('.layer1').css('fill', newValue);
                $('#colorbox1').css('background-color', newValue);
            }
        });
```

Final Solution including the initial loading of each default color into each of the colorboxes:

```
    var numberColors = <?php echo $numColors; ?>;
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        const defaultColors = Array.from(
            { length: numberColors },
            (_, i) => $('.layer' + (i + 1)).css('fill')
        );

        const colorBoxes = $('.colorbox');
        const colorInputs = $('.colorinput');
        $(colorBoxes).each(function (index) {
            $(this).css('background-color', defaultColors[index]);
        });

        colorInputs.on('input', function() {
            const $this = $(this);
            const index = colorInputs.index($this);
            const newColor = $this.val() || defaultColors[index];
            $('.layer' + (index + 1)).css('fill', newColor);
            colorBoxes.eq(index).css('background-color', newColor);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Your second for loop is overwriting the values of the array created in the first for loop.  Also you don't need two for loops.  And you're missing an equals sign in your array declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs should be used for elements that are *unique and distinct*, like a search box. Elements that are simply part of a *collection*, like your `colorbox`es, should not have separate IDs for each item in the collection. For a situation like that, use classes instead. In order to tie the functionality of a color *input* fields (currently your `#color<num>`s) to your color *display* boxes (currently your `#colorbox<num>`s), you can check the index of the changed field in the collection of input fields, and change the `colorbox` with the same index in the collection of colorboxes.

For example, you might use a class name of `colorinput` for the input fields, and a class name of `colorbox` for the colorboxes. On page load, make an *array* for default colors of each `layer`:

```
const defaultColors = Array.from(
  { length: numberColors },
  (_, i) => $('.layer' + (i + 1)).css('fill')
);
```

This means you have a *single variable* which you can access by index rather than using individual variable names for every item, which is repetitive and hard to manage.

The `i + 1` is there because arrays and array indicies (like most things in programming) are zero-indexed, but your `.layer<num>`s start at 1, not at 0.

For the `colorinput`s, to repeat yourself less, put the new color (whether it's the value in the input field or the default color) into a variable *initially*, and then set each `.css` to that variable:

```
const colorBoxes = $('.colorbox');
const colorInputs = $('.colorinput');
colorInputs.on('input', function() {
  const $this = $(this);
  const index = colorInputs.index($this);
  const newColor = $this.val() || defaultColors[index];
  $('.layer' + (index + 1)).css('fill', newColor);
  colorBoxes.eq(index).css('background-color', newColor);
});
```

Again, the `index + 1` in there is because collections are zero-indexed. If you can, you might consider using `.layer<num>` classes where `num` starts at 0 instead, which will simplify the code even more.

Comment: Works great! Thanks. I should be able to handle the initial loading of the colorboxes. I also edited your code to change colorboxes 'fill' property to 'background-color' since they are divs. Your code was very helpful and thanks for taking the time to explain it. I also learned about the eq(). Thanks so much!!!